# Ninject Bind AllClasses when Concrete implements Abstract

Tags: c#, ninject

I have (a very contrived example):

```
interface IStrategy
{
   bool CanHandle(SomeEnum someEnum);

   void Handle(SomeEntity someEntity);

   void ConfigureDb(DbContext context);
}

abstract BaseStrategy : IStrategy
{
   abstract bool CanHandle(SomeEnum someEnum);
 
   abstract void Handle(SomeEntity someEntity);

   virtual void Configure(DbContext context)
   {
       context.LazyLoading = true;
   }
}

class SomeEntityStrategy : BaseStrategy
{
    /* Assume this has been implemented */
}


class SomeOtherEntityStrategy : BaseStrategy
{
    /* Assume this has been implemented */
}
```

So I assumed that:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(IStrategy)).BindDefaultInterface());
```

Would bind all the concrete implementations to the interface `IStrategy`.

In my constructor I do:

```
ctor(IEnumerable<IStrategy> strategies)
```

This comes back with an empty list.

So this may have been answered some where else, but I'm not entirely sure what I should be searching on.

### Edit

So for some reason, that I wouldn't mind having clarified why does `BindAllInterfaces` work???

So my thinking is that Ninject treats abstract classes as interfaces.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get null I get an empty list

Comment: In particular: what is `ctor`? Is it a pointer to a constructor? If so how to you define it?

Comment: it's shorthand for the c# class constructor, it's just an arbitrary c# class constructor

Comment: Well, you cannot expect a constructor to return anything else then an instance of the class where it is defined. So how should a constructor return a list? Or do you want to call the contructor for every class implementing `IStrategy`?

Comment: No, that constructor is for the class wanting to use a list of these `IStrategy`s. So the DI should find all the bindings for the `IStrategy` and give those to the constructor. Just standard DI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have changed the binding slightly:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(IStrategy)).BindDefaultInterfaces());
```

So just the pluralisation is the issue..

My thinking is that Ninject is treating the abstract class an interface so technically there are 2 interfaces that the strategy can be bound to.